# JQuery Datatables in a Sharepoint Web Part

Tags: jquery, .net, datatables

I'm trying to implement jQuery Datatables in a Sharepoint solution.   I'm pretty confident that I have the HTML and the function in place correctly but what I'm confused about is how to call the method in the code behind.  Here's the code:

HTML

```
<table 
ID="tbl_FundingSummary" 
style="width: 95%">
<tr>
<th style="width: 65%; text-align:left; padding-bottom:10px;">Research Area</th>
<th style="width: 15%; text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;">Gross</th>
<th style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;">All Gross</th>
</tr>            
</table>
```

jQuery

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#tbl_FundingSummary')) {
         t.destroy();
     }
     t = $("#tbl_FundingSummary").DataTable({
         processing: true,
         serverSide: true,
         info: true,
         ajax: {
             url: '../DashboardJQD/DashboardJQDUserControl/GetFundingData',
             data: function (data) {
                 delete data.columns;
             }
         },
         columns: [
                     { "data": "PlName" },
                     { "data": "FundingGross" },
                     { "data": "AllGross" }
         ],
         order: [[0, 'desc']],
         select: true,
         dom: 'lfrtip',
         responsive: true,
         buttons: true
     });
     t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
         t.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
             cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
         });
     }).draw();

 });
```

Code behind of the Web Part ascx

```
namespace DashboardJQD
{
public partial class DashboardJQDUserControl : UserControlWithControllerBase<DashboardController>
{
        private string GetFundingData()
    {
        var methodStart = DateTime.Now;
        const string methodName = "GetFundingData";
        var year = 0;

        MyFundingResponse fundingData = null;

        //TEST STUB
        //year = DateTime.Now.Year;
        year = 2015;

        fundingData = Controller.GetFundingData(CurrentUser.UserId, CompanyGroupCode, year.ToString());

        if (fundingData == null)
        {
            RaiseMessage("No data found for this combination");
            return null;
        }

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(fundingData.Summary);

        return serializedResult;
    }
}}
```

I don't think I'm calling the URL correctly, but any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try making the method public?

Comment: Yes, still getting a 404 error

Comment: I've had trouble in the past hitting a web method/controller from an ascx control because they don't have a URL you can hit. You may have to host your method in separate service or an ApiController. Another option is to write the table to your control in it's load event and then just call the data tables constructor on that table element in jQuery. If you don't need an async client call to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out an easy fix.  I implemented a Listview control and then just referenced the table ID

```
    <asp:ListView
    ID="lvFundingSummary"
    OnItemDataBound="lvFundingSummary_ItemDataBound" 
    runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 65%; text-align:left; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblResearchArea" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PlName")%>' />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 15%; text-align:right; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblFundingGross" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FundingGross", "{0:c}")%>' />
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:right; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom:5px;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblGross" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AllGross", "{0:c}")%>' />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table 
            ID="itemPlaceholderContainer" 
            style="width: 100%">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 65%; text-align:left; padding-bottom:10px;">Research Area</th>
                    <th style="width: 15%; text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;">Gross</th>
                    <th style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;">All EPRI Gross</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 65%; text-align:left; padding-bottom:10px;"><b>Total(s)</b></td>
                    <td style="width: 15%; text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;"><b><asp:Label ID="lblTotalFunding" runat="server" /></b></td>
                    <td style="text-align:right; padding-bottom:10px;"><b><asp:Label ID="lblTotalEpriGross" runat="server" /></b></td>
                </tr>          
            </tfoot>

            <tbody runat="server">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </tbody>

        </table>                            
    </LayoutTemplate>          
</asp:ListView>

</div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           var table = $('#itemPlaceholderContainer').dataTable(
               {
                   "scrollY": "300px",
                   "scrollX": true,
                   "scrollCollapse": true,
                   "paging": false,
                   "autowidth": true,

                   dom: 'frti<"floatRight"B><"clear">',
                   buttons: [
                       'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                   ]
               });

       });
 </script>
```